# How to center a "nested div" construction?

Tags: html, css

sorry, I couldnt find out a better name. I have a menu item, in LI:

```
<li level="1"><a href="/"><div class="menuIcons"><div class="menuWrapper"><img src="http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg?w=630&h=420" ><div class="menuText">Home</div></div></div></a></li>

li
{
    width: 50%;
}
a
{
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
}

.menuIcons
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 38px;
}
.menuIcons img
{
    max-width: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
.menuWrapper { display:table; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fyDWN/

I want to align the content to middle, but as you can see, its nested div construction, its not that easy to set "text-align: center;"

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fyDWN/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change css to

```
li
{
    width: 50%;
}
a
{
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    float:left;
}

.menuIcons img
{
    max-width: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/fyDWN/3/

Answer (score 2):

the following will align your li centre and then all of the a tags centred within that

```
<li level="1"><a href="/"><div class="menuIcons"><div class="menuWrapper"><img src="....." ><div class="menuText">Home</div></div></div></a></li>

<style>
li
{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
a
{
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;    
}

.menuIcons
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 38px;
}
.menuIcons img
{
    max-width: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
.menuWrapper { display:table; }
</style>
```